# ExtJS - Get a selected value of a grid on a click of a button

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, sencha-architect

I am a newbie to Ext JS so I am finding a little difficulty in getting this simple logic.

I have a Grid in a tab panel. I have added two buttons 'Add' and 'Update' at the and of this grid. On click of 'Add', I would like to see the value of selected row.

Code is as below:

```js
Ext.define('XYZ.view.PlantInformation', {
      extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
      alias: 'widget.plantinformation',

      requires: [
        'XYZ.view.PlantInformationOldViewModel1',
        'Ext.tab.Panel',
        'Ext.tab.Tab',
        'Ext.grid.Panel',
        'Ext.grid.column.Column',
        'Ext.view.Table',
        'Ext.toolbar.Spacer'
      ],

      viewModel: {
        type: 'plantinformation'
      },
      height: 500,
      width: 800,
      layout: 'fit',
      title: 'Plant Information',
      defaultListenerScope: true,

      items: [{
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        activeTab: 0,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            scrollable: 'true',
            title: 'Plant',
            items: [{
              xtype: 'gridpanel',
              itemId: 'PlantTab',
              scrollable: true,
              bodyBorder: true,
              bind: {
                store: 'PlantStore'
              },
              columns: [{
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'ID_PLANT',
                text: 'Plant ID'
              }, {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'DS_PLANT',
                text: 'Plant Name',
                flex: 1
              }],
              dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                dock: 'bottom',
                width: 100,
                layout: {
                  type: 'hbox',
                  align: 'stretch',
                  pack: 'end'
                },
                items: [{
                  xtype: 'button',
                  flex: 1,
                  text: 'Add',
                  listeners: {
                    click: 'onButtonClick'
                  }
                }, {
                  xtype: 'tbspacer',
                  flex: 1
                }, {
                  xtype: 'button',
                  flex: 1,
                  text: 'Update'
                }]
              }],
              listeners: {
                select: 'onGridpanelSelect'
              }
            }]
          },

        ],

        onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
          var grid = Ext.getCmp('PlantTab');
          var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
          alert(selection);
        },

        onGridpanelSelect: function(rowmodel, record, index, eOpts) {


        }

      });
```

I'm getting a error:

> **Uncaught TypeError**: Cannot read property 'getSelectionModel' of undefined

What am I doing wrong to gt this simple thing?

Thnaks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve your component with `Ext.getCmp`, then replace:

`itemId: 'PlantTab'`

with:

`id: 'PlantTab'`

in your grid config.

`id` is global, `itemId` is scoped within the parent container.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But alert box is stating [Object object} .. How can I get the individual values - like ID_PLANT and DS_PLANT columns ?

Comment: And are there any other method to retirieve grid selected row value than what am I doing?

Comment: There is no such thing as row "value". Each row corresponds to a *record* which is an instance of [`Ext.data.Model`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model). This is exactly what you are retrieving with `grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0]`. So just call `get(fieldName)` on that record to get individual values.

Comment: Well, I tried onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        var grid = Ext.getCmp('PlantTab');
                       var selection= grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                Ext.Msg.alert('Cool' , selection.get('ID_PLANT'));
    }   ... It worked .. Thanks a ton !!